Inquiry About Capturing Focus Loss Events in Lightning App Builder
I am considering developing LWC or Aura components and want to trigger an event when a standard field component placed on a Lightning record page loses focus. Could you advise on how to implement this?
Thank you for your assistance.
What I Tried:
I placed a standard field component in the Lightning Application Builder and attempted to implement a feature that triggers an event when the focus is lost, using JavaScript. Specifically, I tried to use an LWC component to call the addEventListener method to detect a 'blur' event.
What I Expected:
I expected that when the standard field component lost focus, the specified JavaScript event handler would activate and perform certain actions.
